# Visual Studio - How to translate mex code from matlab to C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, matlab, mex

I want to translate a Matlab project in C++ by using Visual Studio.  In my Matlab project I also have some mex file with given code. By given code I mean a `.cc` code with the actual code of the mex function.

How can I use that code directly in C++? I have some functions with the `mx` prefix which I cannot use inside Visual Studio (e.g. `mxGetPr`, `mxGetDimensions`, `mxClassID`).

What do I have to include or add to my project in order to use those functions? Can you give me a starting point of how to translate and use this type of code in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use mex code outside of a Matlab context you would have to rewrite all the mex-specific routines in the source or replace them with non-Matlab versions. For example, everywhere that "mexPrintf" appeared in the mex code you would have to replace it with "printf" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I acknowledge that you want to use Visual Studios. As an alternative suggestion you could get a trial version of Matlab to use the function mcc to convert matlab, or mex, files to c or c++ or dotnet or, almost, whatever you want.